# How to source a file in Mac

Tags: command-line, administrator, serveradmin

I'm from the Linux world where if I want to source a file I type for example:

'source /etc/profile'

How do I do this in Mac?

Comment: Why don't you try it in the same way?

Comment: I have a feeling that the question needs more work.  Coming from a linux box, he should have tried this, and it didn't seem to work.  Perhaps Mr. Parrish would care to explain what the circumstances were that makes think it's not working, or what he is expecting to happen.

Answer (score 6):

Terminal uses Bash by default and /bin/sh is also Bash, so source should work in most places.

[source is not defined by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588583/is-the-shells-source-posix-standard), but it is allowed by Bash in POSIX mode or when it's invoked as /bin/sh.

The help messages for source and . are identical:

```
$ help source .
source: source filename [arguments]
    Read and execute commands from FILENAME and return.  The pathnames
    in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.  If any
    ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
    FILENAME is executed.
.: . filename [arguments]
    Read and execute commands from FILENAME and return.  The pathnames
    in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.  If any
    ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
    FILENAME is executed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using bash as my shell on my Mac and I can use "source".  For example `source .bash_profile`